# Programmatically Navigating React Router V6 From React.Componet

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There is a lot of documentation on how to navigate with React Router V6 when its functional programming and hooks. For instance:

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#navigating-programmatically

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

let navigate = useNavigate();

navigate("/some/url");
```

But there isn't any documentation how to navigate if React.Component is being extended. How can navigation be done programmatically from a React.component?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the only workaround I have been be able to find

```js
import * as React from "react";

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.goTo = this.goTo.bind(this);
  }

  goTo() {
    window.location.href = "/about";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashbaord</h1>
        <button onClick={this.goTo}>Go Home</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: I've been using window.location as well,  but it feels like a hack than leaning into the framework.